# How can I fix React-Native Android affineFormats error

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using `react-native-text-input-mask` library in my React-Native project.
`react-native-text-input-mask` is one of the good libraries to add the text input mask for React-Native on iOS and Android.
It works well on iOS but on Android, I see `affineFormats` error. How can I fix this error?

[image]

Here is my code.

```
<TextInputMask
  style={commonStyles.textInput}
  value={phoneNumber}
  placeholderTextColor="darkgray"
  placeholder="Phone #"
  keyboardType="phone-pad"
  mask={"+1 ([000])-[000]-[0000]"}
  onChangeText={setPhoneNumber}
/>
```

Comment: can you show `setPhoneNumber` please ? If it's a set state, then will it work with the parameters ?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa Yes, correct. I mean it's a state setter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add the missing props.

```
<TextInputMask
  onChangeText={onChangeText}
  value={value}
  affineFormats={[]}
  customNotations={[]}
  affinityCalculationStrategy={'WHOLE_STRING'}
  mask={"[000].[000].[000]"}
/>
```

https://github.com/react-native-text-input-mask/react-native-text-input-mask/issues/217#issuecomment-831844833